# Comparing IP strings doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, string, ip, compare, vpn

Let me just start this with what the program is trying to accomplish before I start with my problem. I'm working on a program that checks every 5 to 10 (not implemented yet) seconds to see if you VPN has dropped the way I'm doing this having the user type in there IP before they start the VPN and then they start the VPN and it checks to see if it changes. My problem is that when I compare the two strings even if they are the same the program stays they are different.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LbIP.Text = GetIP()
    End Sub

    Function GetIP() As String
        Dim IP As New WebClient
        Return IP.DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com/")
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If GetIP() = TextBox1.Text Then
            Label1.Text = "VPN DROPPED"
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Your Good"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you ever try to debug this? You are comparing your user input to the website source string. How could you expect them to be equal?

Comment: Filburt I have and it still doesn't work give it a try for your self

Comment: So you insist that when debugging the return value of `GetIP()` and the property value of `TextBox1.Text` do match but the equality comparision yields false? I tried the service and it returns an IPv6 address - is this what you expect and enter in your TextBox?

Comment: [can i haz ip](http://icanhazip.com/) should return an IPv4 Adress

Comment: From what I see IPv4 is served via [http://ipv4.icanhazip.com/](http://ipv4.icanhazip.com/)

Comment: IPv4 is returned by default if you are not running IPv6 Enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DownloadString will return ip address with \n at the end of the string. you need to remove that and compare.

sample work around

```
  If GetIP().Replace("\n","") = TextBox1.Text Then
            Label1.Text = "VPN DROPPED"
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Your Good"
 End If
```

Comment: Just tested this and it still doesn't work. I tried replacing "" with E and it didn't show E

Comment: Please check my screenshot out here its working.
 Image URL : 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/CchXG.png

Comment: And it's still doing this for me [link](http://gyazo.com/73dcc75ca15980a88ccc7b2ab77c1037)

Comment: Can't you do a variable initialization as i did and take a screenshot of Visual studio debugger (hover variable name then shows value and do not hide last characters)

Comment: Super late response to this but I was looking through my old projects and with updated visual studio this worked thank Keizer.